# Upload picture with MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to upload a picture to my db and im insecure in how to do this properly. I'm using MySQL and PDO

I upload the file through a simple HTML input which links to this PHP file

```
$image =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); //Extract the content of image
$imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); //Extract the mime type (filetype)

$loggedinuser=$_SESSION["ID"];

$sql = "UPDATE UserProfile SET profilePicture=:image, pictureFileType=:imageProperties WHERE UID=:loggedinuser";

// $imageProperties['mine'] value
// $image value

 try {
  $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $st->bindParam(":loggedinuser",$_SESSION["ID"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $st->execute();
  $rows=$st->fetchAll();
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Server Error - try again";
  exit;
 };
```

I dont know how to bind the values or parameter for the picture and filetype.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `addslashes()` should NOT be used. it is NOT a defence against sql injection attacks, and since you're using placeholders, is entirely redundant anyways. and you're doing an update query anyways. there are no rows to fetch. updates do not return result sets.

Comment: your not binding your other variables, `getimagesize` returns an array which you can't bind, etc etc.

Comment: I know im not binding the variables. That is kinda what i need help for :)